# Commutate a Quaternion multiplication

Tags: quaternions, noncommutative-algebra

I have a fixed Quaternion `t` that is defined as `Quaternion([0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5]);`. The order here is `w,i,j,k`.

In my program I have an function that I would like to modify. The function takes `q` as an input and calculates `t*q`.

I would like to calculate a new fixed `tprime` such that `q*tprime` gives me the same result as `t*q`.

I've read about the non commutative properties of Quaternions. But I haven't been able to find a solution to the problem. Is there a general solution? Or is this depend some properties of `t` ? Thanks.

Comment: In other words, the set of operators "multiply by a quaternion on the left" and "multiply by a quaternion on the right" are different sets.

Comment: Alright this works for me! If you change your comment to an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - I think he's talking to you. :-)

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Ok. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ring of quaternions every non-zero element has an inverse. So if $q\neq0$ the only solution $t'$ of the quaternion equation
$$qt'=tq\qquad(*)$$
is (multiply $(*)$ by $q^{-1}$ from the left hand side and apply associativity)
$$
t'=q^{-1}tq.\qquad(**)
$$
Obviously this $t'$ also is a solution — we get $(*)$ as a consequence of $(**)$ by multiplying $(**)$ from the left hand side by $q$.

---

A consequence of this is that $t'$ depends on $q$. This cannot be helped. When you think how composition of rotations corresponds to the product of quaternions, this should not be a surprise. However, the quaternions $t$ and $t'$ have the same real part (check if you don't see it right away), meaning that their resepective angles of rotation are equal, only the axes are different.